# Select query with missing rows or zero values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, coalesce

I'm not skilled at all in Postgres. Limitations are: I'm using someone else's database so no changes to tables can be made. Postgres 8.3.3 and no upgrading allowed. Accessing the database through pgAdmin III from Windows.

I'm running into a block that's killing me. If a value in one table doesn't exist in the associated table, I get no return at all. Table `B` has a numerical column (`C_id`) that references a numerical column (`id`) in Table `C` but is optional in Table `B`, so it can be `0` to indicate empty. There is no 0 record in `C.id`.

I want to select a complete list from Table `B` that replaces the numerical value with a label from Table `C`. This works as long as there is a matching number, but if `B.C_id = 0` I get no line at all for that record. So table `B` has 66 rows but 11 of those have `C_id = 0` so I only get 55 rows in my output.

`WHERE B.C_id = C.id` to match the tables seems to exclude the non-matching rows (`B.C_id = 0`) but if I leave it out, the results loop a 66 records table into 1300+ lines of output (multiplying the two tables' rows). My searching says `COALESCE` or `LEFT JOIN` should work, but `COALESCE` does not change the output. I presume because the disconnect is on `0` not `NULL`. I have not been able to get any statements to work with `LEFT JOIN` or `CASE`.

To complicate matters, both tables are addressed from another table. A simplified example of the structure:

```
Table A: (id, label, B_id)
Table B: (id, label, C_id)
Table C: (id, label)
```

All `id` fields are numbers and labels are text. All records in `A.B_id` contain a non-zero number, but `B.C_id` may contain `0`. No rows exist in any table with `id = 0`.

I want to output to look like:

```
A.label, C.label
```

or, with `B.C_ID = 0`:

```
A.label, 'none'
```

Comment: "*Postgres 8.3.3 and no upgrading allowed*" - good luck with that. 8.3.3. isn't even the latests 8.3 version. You are missing 5 years of bugfixes in the 8.3 line. You are looking for a simple outer join if I understand everything correctly.

Comment: Please do show what you have tried.

Comment: Uh, yeah, I pointed out that I was stuck on 8.3.3 so people wouldn't waste their time telling me to upgrade. I'll do more research on OUTER JOIN. I had seen many similar requests for how to do this, but most were solved using LEFT JOIN (which I can't get to work) or COALESCE which seems to have no effect, at least in my case.

Comment: The error I get when I try LEFT JOIN is: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "B"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: There is an entry for table "B", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
Character: 375

Comment: The command I tried is:  LEFT JOIN C ON (C.id = B.C_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` between tables `B` and `C`. Then [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to provide `'none'` as default if no matching row in `C` is found.

```
SELECT A.label AS a_label, COALESCE(C.label, 'none') AS c_label
FROM      A
JOIN      B ON B.id = A.B_id
LEFT JOIN C ON C.id = B.C_id;
```

Assuming referential integrity between `A` and `B` I use an `[INNER] JOIN` for those.

[Details for joins in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

Comment: Great! Thanks for taking the time to educate an old computer guy. I'm "LEFT JOINING" all over the place and COALESCE is working as I wanted. I'm well on my way to what I wanted. Thanks again.